# Link in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, url

So for a school project I have to read in some data through an api. So far everything (kinda) works, but when I try to read in some data underneath a couple of links, I get keyerrors.
I would not mind posting the entire list, but it is mainly in dutch.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("http://api.buienradar.nl/data/public/2.0/jsonfeed ") as response:
    source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)
#pirnt(json.dumps(data, indent =2))

for item in data['actual']['stationmeasurements']:
    del item['iconurl']
    del item['graphUrl']
    station = item['stationname']
    #regio = item['regio]
    stationid = item['winddirection']
    print(station, stationid)


with open('uitlezen_buienradar.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f , indent=2)
```

This is a part of the list:

```
"$id": "1",
  "buienradar": {
    "$id": "2",
    "copyright": "(C)opyright Buienradar / RTL. Alle rechten voorbehouden",
    "terms": "Deze feed mag vrij worden gebruikt onder voorwaarde van bronvermelding buienradar.nl inclusief een hyperlink naar https://www.buienradar.nl. Aan de feed kunnen door gebruikers of andere personen geen rechten worden ontleend."
  },
  "actual": {
    "$id": "3",
    "actualradarurl": "https://api.buienradar.nl/image/1.0/RadarMapNL?w=500&h=512",
    "sunrise": "2019-10-04T07:45:00",
    "sunset": "2019-10-04T19:11:00",
    "stationmeasurements": [
      {
        "$id": "4",
        "stationid": 6391,
        "stationname": "Meetstation Arcen",
        "lat": 51.5,
        "lon": 6.2,
        "regio": "Venlo",
        "timestamp": "2019-10-04T02:30:00",
        "weatherdescription": "Zwaar bewolkt",
        "iconurl": "https://www.buienradar.nl/resources/images/icons/weather/30x30/cc.png",
        "graphUrl": "https://www.buienradar.nl/nederland/weerbericht/weergrafieken/cc",
        "winddirection": "ZO",
        "temperature": 10.0,
        "groundtemperature": 9.9,
        "feeltemperature": 9.6,
        "windgusts": 2.4,
        "windspeed": 1.5,
        "windspeedBft": 1,
        "humidity": 93.0,
        "precipitation": 0.0,
        "sunpower": 0.0,
        "rainFallLast24Hour": 4.5,
        "rainFallLastHour": 0.0,
        "winddirectiondegrees": 143
```

After 'iconurl' and 'graphurl' it just spews out errors.

Comment: Please post something that we can run and reproduce on or end. Please show the error in its entirety

Comment: Please post error with traceback

Comment: Why are you deleting the entries in the items? You don't do anythin with them?

Comment: I tried to reproduce error and only get error on "winddirection". To avoid errors I suggest to do ALWAYS you want to get a key (if "key" in item:    print(item["key"]) )

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to this site and programming in general. And yes, the urls needed to be deleted. Those were the only 2 that I dont need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict.get(key), then there will be no exception if the key does not exist. Incomplete data in your items ;)

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("http://api.buienradar.nl/data/public/2.0/jsonfeed ") as response:
    source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)
#pirnt(json.dumps(data, indent =2))

for item in data['actual']['stationmeasurements']:
    del item['iconurl']
    del item['graphUrl']
    station = item.get('stationname')
    #regio = item['regio]
    stationid = item.get('winddirection')
    print(station, stationid)


with open('uitlezen_buienradar.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f , indent=2)
```

Comment: And maybe read up on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with dict.get(key). Where should I add that? Or alter the code?

Comment: Oow sorry, I didnt see it. The only question I have now is, why does it do this? I mean, the url has a value right?

Comment: See the explanation of TomMP. And try: `test = {1:2}  test[2]` raises key.error, because the key is `None. test.get(2)` raises no error. So your code is executed. You can check your data with print(item) in the loop to see the structure of the dicts. Some have not the desired key.